# A Hadoop DataNode error: host:port authority

Tags: hadoop

guys.when I try to run the hadoop cluster ,but i don't make it .The main error  is like this:[image: the datanode log]

But the strong strange is that the NameNode,JobTracker,SecondNameNode  and TaskTracker are ok,besides the dataNode .

My other configurations are like these:

hdfs-site.xml
 [image: hdfs-site.xml]

core-site.xml 
[image: core-site.xml]

mapred-site.xml
[image: mapred-site.xml]

Comment: Can you post what your log files say?

Comment: The first picture is the log. when i run it ,the stdin is no error. only datanode-slave1.log has error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it would help, but [check this page](http://www.senthilb.com/2012/10/hadoop-single-node-setup.html)

To quote from there,

> Even thought I configured the core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml &
>   hdfs-site.xml under /usr/local/hadoop/conf/ folder, by default the
>   system is referring to /etc/hadoop/ *.xml. Once I update the
>   configuration files in /etc/hadoop location everything started
>   working.

Comment: thanks, I have got the situation what you said ，but not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are picking the correct set of configuration files. Looks like some classpath related issue since your setup is bypassing whatever you have configured in your **core-site.xml**. Make sure you don't have any classpath related issue. Do you have any other Hadoop setup on the same machine, which was done earlier, and then you forgot to edit the classpath for the current setup?

Also, **http://** is not required in **mapred-site.xml**.

HTH

Comment: yeah,but how to confirm whether there is some classpath related issue. I have used "strace -fe open start-all.sh" to analysis ，but have no found.

Comment: I have setup a x64_86.rpm ,but i found it's work .so i uninstall it ,includes all the dir. i don't think this is the point.